# Checking Svelte version from a command line

Tags: command-line, svelte

I am new to svelte and I want to know how to display the version number of the installed svelte version in the command line. Note that I installed svelte by using degit.

I tried 'npx svelte --version' in the command line but got an error 'npm ERR! could not determine executable to run'. Note: I got that command from chatgpt.

Comment: ChatGPT is just hallucinating, it is not giving you real advice.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 4):

You can check versions of any Node packages with `npm ls` command.

For UNIX command line you can do:

```bash
npm ls|grep -i svelte
```

And you get output like:

```
├── @sveltejs/adapter-node@1.2.4
├── @sveltejs/kit@1.20.1
├── @testing-library/svelte@3.2.2
├── eslint-plugin-svelte3@4.0.0
├── prettier-plugin-svelte@2.10.1
├── svelte-check@3.4.3
├── svelte-fsm@1.2.0
├── svelte-headless-table@0.17.3
├── svelte-highlight@7.2.1
├── svelte-inview@4.0.0
├── svelte-preprocess@5.0.4
├── svelte-spinner@2.0.2
├── svelte@3.59.1
```

Comment: Time to update your Svelte!  3.59?  How come? :-)